# How to fetch entities in db while using doctrine fixtures?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have been the ContainerAwareInterface on my LoadAdvert class so I can call and use the EntityManager to retrieve users in the database.

However, when executing php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load, the entity manager retrieves only an empty array, as if there was no user in the db.

```
<?php
// src/OC/PlatformBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadCategory.php

namespace OC\PlatformBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert;
use OC\UserBundle\Entity\User;

   class LoadAdvert implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
    {
      /**
       * @var ContainerInterface
       */
      private $container;

      public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
      {
        $this->container = $container;
      }

      // Dans l'argument de la méthode load, l'objet $manager est l'EntityManager
      public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
      {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $author = $em->getRepository('OCUserBundle:User')->findAll();

        die(var_dump($author));
```

Comment: What you try to do? Do you know what does doctrine data fixtures?

Comment: I am trying to get all the users and use them to hydrate my adverts before inserting them into the db.

Comment: your class shoud extend `use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;` ?

Comment: You will be better served if you add a users fixture or create users in this fixture  - this will further separate your tests from your dev & prod database.

Comment: I was thinking about that, geoB. The thing is that I am using the FOSUserBundle and don't know how to create data fixtures for it.

Comment: The same way as normal entity, just create new user object and insert it to db. Back to main problem, when you run `doctrine:fixtures:load` the database is dropped, so you cannot fetch users who don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is how I do it. The main thing is to set reference for user objects that you create and then call it in other fixture file and assign them to related objects. Also its important the order of execution of fixture data. You cant load related object before you load users.

```
namespace AcmeBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LoadUserData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /** @var  ContainerInterface */
    private $container;

    /**
     * Load data fixtures with the passed EntityManager
     *
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $user1 = $userManager->createUser();
        $user1->setUsername('username1');
        $user1->setPlainPassword('123');
        $user1->setEmail('example1@gmail.com');
        $user1->setEnabled(true);


        $user2 = $userManager->createUser();
        $user2->setUsername('username2');
        $user2->setPlainPassword('123');
        $user1->setEmail('example2@gmail.com');
        $user2->setEnabled(true);

        $manager->persist($user1);
        $manager->persist($user2);

        $this->setReference('user1', $user1);
        $this->setReference('user2', $user2);

        $manager->flush();
    }

    /**
     * Get the order of this fixture
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the Container. Need it to create new User from fos_user.user_manager service
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface|null $container A ContainerInterface instance or null
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

Then in other fixture file you dont call user as you did from database, you do it like this:

```
 $author = $this->getReference('user1');

 $article = new Article();
 $article->addAuthor($author);
```

and then you add this `$author` object to related object.

Keep in mind to implement `OrderedFixtureInterface` in this `article` fixture and set `getOrder()` to be higher number than the one for `users`.

Comment: Purrfect ! Thank you so much, Lord Zed !

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.